# How can I control power fed by a DC Voltage source in Simulink?

Tags: matlab, simulink

I want to restrict the power fed by one voltage source and in case of demand, want another voltage source to feed the power. Can anyone suggest how to go about it ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I suggest you to formulate your question properly and post it on [EE.SE](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Do you actually want to do this or simulate a system that would do this?